# JQuery - Set array element as attribute value for every <li>

Tags: jquery, arrays, foreach

I have an array `arrayDescr` and I need to use `forEach` to add to every `<li>` an attribute `data-value`. The value of `data-value` should be an `arrayDescr` element. For example I have three `<li>`'s and I have two `arrayDescr` elements. Two of three `<li>`'s should have attribute `data-value` `arrayDescr[0]`, [1] and etc.

This code works but I need it to work in forEach:

```
$("#name1").attr("data-value", arrayDescr[0])
```

#name should be  function(){return 'name' (i+1)}.
In forEach this code returns `undefined`:

```
arrayDescr.forEach(function(item, index){
$("li").attr("data-value", item[index])}
```

Comment: @RyanWilson I need an element of array, not the whole array to be in data-value

Comment: in your `.forEach`, the function parameter `item` is a single item of the array, that's why you get undefined by this `item[index]`

Comment: @RyanWilson arrayDescr.forEach(function(item, index){
     $("#responseul").append("<li class='list-group-item'>  Name: " + item + "</li>");}); this code works and creates every li with every element of array in order. but when i use item without [index] it gives me undefined and sets attribute value 3

Comment: Great, does that mean you solved your own problem?

Comment: for some reason item working properly  only when i append li, not when i set item as attribute value

Comment: Don't mark jQuery questions as JavaScript and if you want to succeed in the long term don't condemn yourself by committing to a framework or library when you should be learning pure JavaScript that won't break or kill performance. Good luck.

Comment: I've made a solution. No need for i+1, i just made 'id="name' + index + '"'

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Vanilla Solution

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
elem[i].setAttribute("data-value", "set value here, or determine how to make it dynamic"+i);
}
```

I haven't tested it on my end, but confident this should do what you want without JQuery and it be acceptable across many browsers (including mobile).

```
for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
elem[i].setAttribute("data-value", (YourDescArray[i] !== undefined)?YourDescArray[i]:"problem");
}
```

Comment: Fighting the good fight: providing the OP with a real JavaScript answer; jQuery needs to be purged from Earth.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be iterating over `li` elements and set their attributes in the `forEach` like

```
$("li").each(function(i,item){
    if(arrayDescr.length > i)
        $(item).attr("data-value",arrayDescr[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate li element and assign attr like below

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
     if(index<arrayDescr.length){
       $( this ).attr("data-value", arrayDescr[index]) ;
   }
});
```